# RxJS SwitchMap doesn't complete if results returned are empty

Tags: typescript, rxjs, observable

I have a datatable which displays a loading spinner. when `this.rendering` gets set to true the loader shows, however - if the results returned from `this._CollectionDataSet.results` are an empty array, the sequence gets stuck at switchMap and doesn't complete - why is this?

[image]

datasource.ts

```
connect(): Observable<Collection[]> {
    // Listen for any changes in the base data, sorting, filtering, or pagination
    const displayDataChanges = [
        this._CollectionDataSet.dataChange,
        this._sort.sortChange
    ];

    return Observable.merge(...displayDataChanges)
        .startWith(null)
        .switchMap(() => {
            this.rendering = true;
            return this._CollectionDataSet.dataChange;
        })
        .catch(() => {
            return Observable.of(null);
        })
        .map((result) => {
            this.rendering = false;
            return result;
        })
        .map(result => {
            if (!result) { return []; }

            this._recordsTotal = result.length;

            const sortedData = this.sortData(result.slice());

            this.renderedData = sortedData;

            return this.renderedData;
        });
}
```

dataset.ts

```
dataChange: BehaviorSubject<Collection[]> = new BehaviorSubject<Collection[]>([]);
get results(): Collection[] { return this.dataChange.value; }

constructor(
    private _collectionService: CollectionService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router
) {
    this.route.params.subscribe((param: any) => {
        this._collectionService.view(param.id).subscribe((results) => this.update(results));
    });
}

update(results: Collection[]) {
    results && this.dataChange.next(results);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't show us how `_CollectionDataSet.results` is defined, but based on the signature you provided

```
(): Collection[]
```

I assume `results` is of type `Collection[]`. The problem here is that `switchMap` has to return an *Observable*. If you already have the data you want to map to, there's no need for an observable and you can just use `map` instead.

Furthermore, you should run side effects using side effect operators (`do` or `tap` when using `pipe`). This reduces your code to

```
.do(() => this.rendering = true)
.map((): Collection[] => this._CollectionDataSet.results)
.catch(result => Observable.of(null))
.do(() => this.rendering = false)
```

Although these side effects are probably rather useless. If `results` is indeed just an array, then all of this will happen instantaneously and you might as well not show a spinner for that.

Comment: I tried to pass in this._CollectionDataSet.dataChange - which is a behavior subject that emits periodically - this still doesn't work, as the loader never gets shown. confusing.

Comment: You'll have to show more code = all code needed to have a reproducible situation. No one can help you if we don't know what variable contains which kind of data.

Comment: Given that rendering is set and the spinner isn't showing, perhaps this is an issue with the spinner itself?

Comment: it works if I put if (result.length) this.rendering = false, but then loader shows forever if no results - crazy!

Comment: Are you sure that the observable doesn't just emit so quickly that the spinner never gets a chance to show? Note that currently the spinner stops showing as soon as the inner observable emits, not when it completes.